# In a locally compact 2nd-countable Hausdorff space $E$ there is a sequence of compact subsets $K_n$ with $K_{n-1}⊆\overset∘{K_n}$ and $\bigcup_nK_n=E$

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation, compactness, second-countable

Let $(E,\tau)$ be a locally compact second-countable Hausdorff space. I want to show that there is a $(K_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}\subseteq E$ such that $K_n$ is compact and $K_{n-1}\subseteq\overset{\circ}{K_n}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N_0}K_n=E$.

The question is basically [answered on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/45691/91890), but there is a part of the proof that I don't understand.

Since $E$ is second-countable, $\tau$ has a countable basis $\mathcal B$. It's easy to see that $$\mathcal B_c:=\left\{U\in\mathcal B:\overline U\text{ is compact}\right\}$$ is again a basis of $\tau$.

Now, the construction described in the answer is as follows:
Let $U_0\in\mathcal B_c$ and $K_0:=\overline{U_0}$. Given $(U_0,K_0),\ldots,(U_{n-1},K_{n-1})$, let $U_n\in\mathcal B_c\setminus\left\{U_0,\ldots,U_{n-1}\right\}$, $\mathcal C$ be a finite subcover of $K_{n-1}$ and $K_n:=\overline{U_n}\cup\overline{C}$.

The problematic part is the cover $\mathcal C$ of $K_{n-1}$ (why *sub*cover?). Can $\mathcal C$ really be arbitrary? What if we choose $\mathcal C=E$?

Comment: Does that $\overset{\circ}{K_n}$ mean interior of $K_n$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly, it cannot be arbitrary. This is my interpretation:

As $\mathcal B_c$ is a basis of $E$, it is a covering of $K_{n-1}$. As $K_{n-1}$ is compact, there is a finite subcover $\mathcal C=\{B_1, B_2,..., B_n\}$ of $K_{n-1}$. Then $C=\bigcup B_i$ and $\overline C= \overline {B_1}\cup \overline {B_2}\cup...\cup \overline {B_n}$ is compact.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I guess the desired inclusion property holds, since $\overset{\circ}{K_n}\supseteq\overset{\circ}{\overline C}\cup\overset{\circ}{\overline{U_n}}\supseteq\overset{\circ}{\overline C}\supseteq \overset{\circ}C=C\supseteq K_{n-1}$, right?

Comment: @0xbadf00d it looks flawless to me.

Comment: Assuming $\tau$ is induced by a metric $d$, it looks intuitively trivial that $d(\partial K_n,∂K_{n+1})>0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N_0$. How can we show it formally? Since $∂K_n\subseteq K_n\subseteq\overset\circ{K_{n+1}}$, we should clearly have $d\left(\overset\circ{K_{n+1}},\partial K_{n+1}\right)\le d\left(K_n,\partial K_{n+1}\right)\le d\left(∂K_n,∂K_{n+1}\right)$. So, it would be sufficient to show that the left-hand side is positive and hence it would be sufficient to show that the distance of the interior and the boundary of a closed (or compact?) set is positive. Can this be done?

Comment: @0xbadf00d I don't think so. Consider a closed ball in $\Bbb R^2$, the distance between the interior and boundary is $0$.

Comment: I see. But do you think $d(\partial K_n,∂K_{n+1})>0$ is wrong too?

Comment: @0xbadf00d It's true. As $\partial K_n$ is compact, $d(\partial K_n,\partial K_{n+1})=d(x_n,x_{n+1})$ for some $x_n\in \partial K_n$ and $x_{n+1}\in \partial K_{n+1}$ (extreme value theorem). As $\partial K_n\subset \text{int} K_{n+1}$ and  $\text{int} K_{n+1}\cap \partial K_{n+1}=\emptyset$, $x_n\notin \partial K_{n+1}$, which means $d(x_n,x_{n+1})>0$

Comment: Ah, sure. Thank you.