# Chain of compact sets in locally compact space

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, compactness, second-countable

When a topological Hausdorff space X is locally compact and second-countable (has countable weight), can we find a chain of compact sets $\{K_i: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, where

- $K_0 = \emptyset$ and
- $K_n \subseteq \operatorname{int} K_{n+1}$
- $\bigcup_n K_n = X$ ?

My intuition is that yes, but I am interested in a formal proof. Also, I am not sure, if we really need the secon-countability. I would say that compact neighborhood of any point is enough to create such infinite sequence of sets.

Also, if the space isn´t locally compact, could we still find such chain?

Thank you.

Comment: You're probably not asking what you want to ask. As currently stated, you can simply pick $K_n=\emptyset$ for all $n$. Anyway, before trying to prove anything, I suggest you really think about why the hypotheses are the way they are before making any guesswork. The fact that you're asking for a *sequence* of compacta certainly points in the direction of a countability assumption. Have you thought about some examples, e.g. an uncountable discrete space?

Comment: I've added the requirement that the $K_n$ cover $X$, as is usual; I think you forgot that demand. Are you assuming $X$ is Hausdorff, or else what definition of local compactness are you using?

Comment: You need second countable, counterexample: uncountable discrete space. You also need locally compact, counterexample: $\mathbb{Q}$ (it doesn't even have compact subsets with nonempty interior).

Comment: You can take a look at https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+compact+and+second-countable+spaces+are+sigma-compact

Comment: Or here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3224571/in-a-locally-compact-2nd-countable-hausdorff-space-e-there-is-a-sequence-of-co?rq=1

Comment: local compactness is necessary if the $K_n$ must cover $X$, that is easy to see.